# webbrowser.open on DataFrame entry

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas' DataFrame like this:

```
listings_df = pd.DataFrame({'prices': prices,
                            'listing_links': listing_links,
                            'photo_links': photo_links,
                            'listing_names': listing_names})
```

`photo_links` list contains URLs to photos. Say I want to get a link straight from the dataframe and open it in webbrowser like this:

```
link_to_open = listings_df.loc[1:1,'photo_links']
webbrowser.open(link_to_open)
```

However the link does not open and I get a 404 error, because the link is stored in the dataframe (or at least printed) in a shortened version:

```
https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/70976075/b
```

versus the original link as it is stored in the `photo_links` list:

```
https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/70976075/b20d9efc_original.jpg?aki_policy=large
```

The question is, how do I access full link from within dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`link_to_open = listings_df.loc[1:1,'photo_links']` returns Series object.

try this

```
link_to_open = listings_df.loc[1,'photo_links']
```